Start-Process ArgumentList wont work properly in Powershell
I am trying to start a java-process with Start-Process in Powershell. I am passing the parameters in the ArgumentList but it seems to cut the argumentlist after a bit.
This is what I have tried:
Start-Process -FilePath java.exe -ArgumentList "-jar C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar", "-jnlpUrl http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp", "-secret 1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890", "-workDir 'e:\myFolder\Jenkins\'"

Start-Process -FilePath java.exe -ArgumentList @("-jar C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar", "-jnlpUrl http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp", "-secret 1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890", "-workDir 'e:\myFolder\Jenkins\'")

...and a few similar formattings, with no luck.
Most of the times I can see the java.exe-process starting for a fragment of a second, and after recording it I can see that it seems to cut the argumentlist in the middle of the secret key. What am I doing wrong here?

if you do "-jar C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar" instead of "-jar", "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar" it's seen as a single argument instead of as a parameter and an argument if that makes sense

Thanks for the fast reply! :)
I have also tried ArgumentList "-jar", "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar"... . . .
It still cuts in the middle somewhere.

right but you need to do that for all parameters and arguments, separate them

Yeah, I did. But I see now that I messed up the quotationmarks in my latest attempt. It works now! :) Thank you very much!

As a side note: The activity manager in windows seem to have limitations in the display length of the "command line" column. So it did not display the last parameter of the argumentlist. But when I read the process information with powershell, all the information was there.

@SantiagoSquarzon, due to a bug in Start-Process you do not need to separate option names and values (you do in direct invocation, however). This is owed to a long-standing Start-Process bug. The only problem here is the use of embedded single-quoting in the "-workDir 'e:\myFolder\Jenkins\'" argument.

From comments the issue is now solved by splitting parameters and arguments instead of putting them together, in summary, this works:
Start-Process -FilePath java.exe -ArgumentList @(
    '-jar'
    'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar'
    '-jnlpUrl'
    'http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp'
    '-secret'
    '1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890'
    '-workDir'
    'e:\myFolder\Jenkins\'
)

But for future, something that makes it really easy to troubleshoot is to compile print_argv.exe taken from jborean93's comment here (Note that it will only compile in Windows PowerShell 5.1 if using Add-Type). Then you can use this command to troubleshoot really easy, to show a comparison of what you had before and after splitting arguments how it looks:
# This is before, using `@(...)` to make it more readable
.\print_argv.exe @(
    '-jar C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar'
    '-jnlpUrl http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp'
    '-secret 1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890'
    "-workDir 'e:\myFolder\Jenkins\'"
)

# [0] -jar C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar
# [1] -jnlpUrl http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp
# [2] -secret 1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890
# [3] -workDir 'e:\myFolder\Jenkins\'

So as you can see, this is parsed as 4 arguments, instead of you separate parameter and arguments:
# This is after, using `@(...)` to make it more readable
.\print_argv.exe @(
    '-jar'
    'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar'
    '-jnlpUrl'
    'http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp'
    '-secret'
    '1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890'
    '-workDir'
    'e:\myFolder\Jenkins\'
)

# [0] -jar
# [1] C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar
# [2] -jnlpUrl
# [3] http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp
# [4] -secret
# [5] 1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890
# [6] -workDir
# [7] e:\myFolder\Jenkins\

This is parsed as 8 arguments which explains why it was failing before.

The only immediate problem with your attempt is the use of embedded single quotes ('...') inside your "-workDir 'e:\myFolder\Jenkins\'" argument, which java.exe doesn't understand.
Thus, replacing this argument with "-workDir `"e:\myFolder\Jenkins\\`"", i.e. using embedded double quotes would fix your problem.
Plus, the last \ must be doubled to prevent it from being interpreted as part of an escape sequence, \", i.e. an escaped " char.
(Since e:\myFolder\Jenkins\ happens not to contain any spaces, you could omit quoting around it altogether.)
The fact that your command then works - despite not passing option names (e.g. -workdir) and their values (e.g, e:\myFolder\Jenkins\) in separate array elements - is a happy accident, owed to a long-standing bug in Start-Process:

It simply joins the verbatim values of the array elements with spaces when building the process command line behind the scenes, and therefore neglects to perform on-demand "..."-quoting of elements that contains spaces.

It is therefore generally better to encode all arguments passed to -ArgumentList in a single string, e.g. -ArgumentList '-foo "bar baz"', because the situational need to use embedded double-quoting is then obvious - see this answer for details.
Applied to your command, using outer single-quoting ('...') for simplicity (since you're not using string interpolation):
# Pass the entire argument list as a single string.
Start-Process -FilePath java.exe -ArgumentList '-jar C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890 -workDir "e:\myFolder\Jenkins\\"'


Taking a step back, the usual advice applies:
To synchronously execute console applications or batch files in the current console (terminal), do not use Start-Process (or the System.Diagnostics.Process API it is based on), except in unusual circumstances.
See this answer and this guidance.
Instead, call them directly** (some.exe or c:\path\to\some.exe ... or & 'c:\path with spaces\to\some.exe' ... or & $exePathStoredInVariable ...).
This also allows you to capture their output directly and to later query their exit code via $LASTEXITCODE.
In a direct call, if you wanted to use an array to pass the arguments, you would indeed have to pass option names and values in individual elements.
Applied to your case:
# Synchronously executes java.exe, allowing you to capture the output,
# and to query the exit code later with $LASTEXITCODE.
java.exe @(
  '-jar'
  'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar'
  '-jnlpUrl'
  'http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp'
  '-secret'
  '1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890'
  '-workDir'
  'e:\myFolder\Jenkins\'
)

The above is the same as:
java.exe -jar C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkins.mysecretdomain.com:8080/manage/computer/myJenkinsNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890abcdefgh1234567890 -workDir e:\myFolder\Jenkins\

